# How do I parse this html with Python lxml & xpath that finds the parent table of a specific span id?

Tags: python-3.x, xpath, lxml

Here is the HTML I don't have any control over. This is condensed HTML of the real page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Little League</title>
</head>
<body>
<table>
<span>lot of unrelated text</span>
</table>
<table>
<span>lot of unrelated text</span>
</table>
<table>
<span>lot of unrelated text</span>
</table>
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="rightTD">
<p>
<span id="teams_players">Player Teams</span>
</p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="tableBorder table table-bordered" width="100%">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
<table border="0" width="100%" class="tableData">
<tbody>
<tr id="team_listings">
<td colspan="3">Team Listings
<br>
<br>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>(a) </td>
<td colspan="2">Team Name </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td colspan="2">
<span class="blue_color">Foxes</span>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>(b) </td>
<td colspan="2">Team Rank</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td colspan="2">
<span class="blue_color">1</span>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>(c) </td>
<td colspan="2">Team Location
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td colspan="2">
<table width="100%">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>City:
<br>
<span class="blue_color">Tualatin</span>
</td>
<td>State:
<br>
<span class="blue_colorLined"></span>
<br>
<span class="blue_color">Oregon</span>
</td>
<td>Country:
<br>
<span class="blue_colorLined"></span>
<br>
<span class="blue_color">United States</span>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>

</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<br>
<table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="tableBorder table table-bordered" width="100%">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
<table border="0" width="100%" class="tableData">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>(a) </td>
<td colspan="2">Team Name </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td colspan="2">
<span class="blue_color">Tigers</span>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>(b) </td>
<td colspan="2">Team Rank</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td colspan="2">
<span class="blue_color">3</span>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>(c) </td>
<td colspan="2">Team Location
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td colspan="2">
<table width="100%">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>City:
<br>
<span class="blue_color">Tigard</span>
</td>
<td>State:
<br>
<span class="blue_colorLined"></span>
<br>
<span class="blue_color">Oregon</span>
</td>
<td>Country:
<br>
<span class="blue_colorLined"></span>
<br>
<span class="blue_color">United States</span>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>

</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

I am trying to get to the table tag **immediately preceding** the span tag with id **team_players**.

I tried these but failed -

```
//table/span[@id="teams_players"]
ancestor::table[span[@id="teams_players"][position() = 1]]
```

This works but is not elegant and I prefer not to hardcode it -

```
//span[@id="teams_players"]/../../../../..
```

While `//table[@class="tableData"]` this might seem like it should work, there are many such tables in the HTML that has the same class with unrelated data. So this is ruled out.

Here is the code so far with my attempts (definitely not efficient, once I find a way of fetching both tables, I plan on looping through them to extract the data -

```
def parse_team():

    # team data structure
    teams = []
    team_dict = { 'team': '', 'rank': '', 'location': { 'city': '', 'state': '', 'country': '' } }

    filename = f'team.html'
    f = open(filename, encoding="utf8").read()
    parser = etree.HTMLParser()
    tree = etree.parse(StringIO(f), parser)

    # fetch the table dom and parse each team table
    # fetch the parent table that contains teams_players span id
    team_tables = tree.xpath('ancestor::table[span[@id="teams_players"][position() = 1]]')
    print(team_tables)

    root_tables = tree.xpath('//table/span[@id="teams_players"]')
    print("root tables", root_tables)

    # this provides each team table but in full html, the same class is being used for other unrelated data
    name = tree.xpath('//table[@class="tableData"]')
    print(name)

    eachvaltr = name[0].xpath('.//tr')
    teamname = name[0].xpath('.//td[contains(text(),"Team Name")]//parent::tr/following-sibling::tr[1]//span[@class="blue_color"]/text()')
    print("teamname", teamname)
    teamrank = name[0].xpath(
        './/td[contains(text(),"Team Rank")]//parent::tr/following-sibling::tr[1]//span[@class="blue_color"]/text()')
    print("teamrank", teamrank)
    city = name[0].xpath(
        './/td[contains(text(),"City")]//span[@class="blue_color"]/text()')
    state = name[0].xpath(
        './/td[contains(text(),"State")]//span[@class="blue_color"]/text()')
    country = name[0].xpath(
        './/td[contains(text(),"Country")]//span[@class="blue_color"]/text()')
    print(city[0], state[0], country[0])
    team_dict['team'] = teamname
    team_dict['rank'] = teamrank
    team_dict['location']['city'] = city[0]
    team_dict['location']['state'] = state[0]
    team_dict['location']['country'] = country[0]

    print(team_dict)
```

Desired output is a list of teams where each team is a dict.

```
[{'team': ['Foxes'], 'rank': ['1'], 'location': {'city': 'Tualatin', 'state': 'Oregon', 'country': 'United States'}}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`//table[.//span[@id="teams_players"]]`

or

`//span[@id="teams_players"]/ancestor::table`

Comment: This worked, can you please explain the [.//span... notation?

Comment: Certainly. A predicate (the part in the square brackets) contains an xpath that determines which nodes to select. This would read in English as "Select the `table` elements that have `span` descendants that have an `id` attribute equal to 'teams_players". The `.` in the xpath selects the current node, that is, the `table` being evaluated.